# which signal can be used to suspend process temporary in linx

Tags: linux, unix, signals

I want to know that which signal can be used to suspend process itself and then it can be resumed  using SIGINT that ctrl +C
well I am trying to do
as 
raise(SIGTSTP);
but it permanently stop process

Answer (score 2):

SIGSTOP stops a process, and

SIGCONT resumes it (not SIGINT)

A process that is stopped by SIGSTOP can not be set to resume on receiving a certain key, because it isn't processing anything while it is stopped, but a parent or another process could be programmed to continue a child on receiving a key...

Answer (score 2):

You could send a `SIGTSTP` or `SIGSTOP` signal to a process, but that process should later be resumed by a `SIGCONT` signal (to be sent by some other process, perhaps the shell).

Read the [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page and the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book.